# Use the value an XML element as a variable for a procedure

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net

I am new to working with XML in VB and I trying use the value of an Element DBName to find the the active SQL database name to connect to.  I have looked over a lot of code but it has just made more confused. Any help would be great!

Below is the code for the sub I am trying to use the variable in.  I am trying to get the DBName from an xml document. The structure of the xml is as follows

```
<db>
<User>DBUser2</User>
<Password><![CDATA[xka2bOHaQZWesxHLFHlWaVw7JscbNFCobXbqYWc5rwppoNkAn3K1uqriSCHdEzyY/FNDdbgRJTzDEIM8Jc5PYTBzfMUC5UIDtr16a64Xj7MRGI4/AvRcys/fIQDZQ947GesAc1rF/kbZu8AaZDVTjwObbNPT2L/h+IA6WjM9lqv6BOCi4dUeKxx5AneCBy2TJdifxEPdAIOT9lqTm5/aHFD0JgqSn0OTtWbLuYX9KX9uvA8L8zEH51yEmGl258aRVfpGfyxph/cpdnW1miRk4Q==]]></Password>
<Server>N127.0.0.1\CESSQL</Server>
<ServerDatabase>Marino</ServerDatabase>
<BackupServer></BackupServer>
<BackupDatabase></BackupDatabase>
<MasterPassword><![CDATA[EFmUxlkmQfIx4w18oQZ1dtCxAIXIyBZPCelL8csYX3E5NuHBZNI42UXNhFxmu87Ksj5CbQpC1WNTj4jnLaaq7nX6Oa4z3M7glLAeRaXWGAd3VqWfADRQAW3RCKKSJRMK3jwRWHJjY1Vp2hgn9CuMACvYHZUrUyK6nJ9HMiwaXcUJKtm4vl0toQNpwIuGvT2cfMJgvpjXJhTBfxKE75ZWeAldXhX5h/c6LYMQ6DE79uuhdbisfmIrXTskKTcceiRjWU2jTFumpjhM1tUqEoBFLw==]]></MasterPassword>
```

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
        Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
        Dim m_node As XmlNode
        m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
        m_xmld.Load("C:\FPOS5\Data\dbinfo.xml")
        m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/DB/ServerDatabase")
        For Each m_node In m_nodelist
        Dim ServerDatabaseValue =    m_node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("ServerDatabase").Value
        Console.Write(ServerDatabaseValue)
        Next

    Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1\CESSQL;database=" & DBName & ";User ID=;Password=")
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim DriverNumber2 As Integer
    Dim CheckNumber2 As Integer

    DriverNumber2 = TextBox1.Text
    CheckNumber2 = TextBox2.Text

    Try
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
    cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Update Sale Set DriverID =" & DriverNumber2 & "where CheckNumber =" & CheckNumber2 & "")


    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

    MsgBox("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: There are several ways of reading XML.  You could use `XDocument`, `XmlDocument`, `XmlSerializer`, or `XmlReader`, among other options.  Do you have a preference?  What have you tried

Comment: i added some additional coding with XmlDocument based on some reading I believe it will get me the result I need but I am still not sure how to get that result to be my variable for my database name.

Comment: You might not want to have your passwords displayed in the question.

Comment: i starred the password for that particular reason. suppose i could just leave that off anyways... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about how to read from an XML file, here is an example.

Assuming this is declared:

```
Dim xml = <db>
            <User>DBUser2</User>
            <Password><![CDATA[xka2bOHaQZWesxHLFHlWaVw7JscbNFCobXbqYWc5rwppoNkAn3K1uqriSCHdEzyY/FNDdbgRJTzDEIM8Jc5PYTBzfMUC5UIDtr16a64Xj7MRGI4/AvRcys/fIQDZQ947GesAc1rF/kbZu8AaZDVTjwObbNPT2L/h+IA6WjM9lqv6BOCi4dUeKxx5AneCBy2TJdifxEPdAIOT9lqTm5/aHFD0JgqSn0OTtWbLuYX9KX9uvA8L8zEH51yEmGl258aRVfpGfyxph/cpdnW1miRk4Q==]]></Password>
            <Server>N127.0.0.1\CESSQL</Server>
            <ServerDatabase>Marino</ServerDatabase>
            <BackupServer></BackupServer>
            <BackupDatabase></BackupDatabase>
            <MasterPassword><![CDATA[EFmUxlkmQfIx4w18oQZ1dtCxAIXIyBZPCelL8csYX3E5NuHBZNI42UXNhFxmu87Ksj5CbQpC1WNTj4jnLaaq7nX6Oa4z3M7glLAeRaXWGAd3VqWfADRQAW3RCKKSJRMK3jwRWHJjY1Vp2hgn9CuMACvYHZUrUyK6nJ9HMiwaXcUJKtm4vl0toQNpwIuGvT2cfMJgvpjXJhTBfxKE75ZWeAldXhX5h/c6LYMQ6DE79uuhdbisfmIrXTskKTcceiRjWU2jTFumpjhM1tUqEoBFLw==]]></MasterPassword>
          </db>
```

It's just one line of code:

```
xml.Element("ServerDatabase").Value
```

Or, to keep your variable names:

```
Dim ServerDatabaseValue As String = xml.Element("ServerDatabase").Value
```

Always specify variable types. To help you with that, you can set `Option Strict On` and `Option Infer Off` in your project settings. This can improve your code quality by forcing you into certain (good) development habits.

Comment: The xml data is from a file not being declared as you have listed. I am loading the file with XmlDocument.  can I identify the element in a similar fashion with this setup?

Comment: @FallingWax: You can use this: `Dim xml As XDocument =  XDocument.Load("C:\FPOS5\Data\dbinfo.xml")`. Then I believe you need to change `xml.Element` to `xml.Root.Element`, rest is the same. [Link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx). The above was just to illustrate the concept. The `XDocument` approach is modular, so any part of it can be customized, i.e. account for multiple nodes, no match etc., with little to no maintenance effort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly sure what you want but you will need to parse the XML and use the XML nodes/element in your connection string. I am not sure even it is a good idea, see this link for parsing XML in VB it is easy.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4826/XML-File-Parsing-in-VB-NET